# SweetAlert2 : Some difficults to configure my alert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, confirm, sweetalert2

I'm trying to use sweetAlert2. https://sweetalert2.github.io/

The plan is as follows:

1) Display of the main alert

2) If he clicks on "Cancel", I close the alert normally.

3) If he clicks on "OK", then the button goes to the loading position, but the alert does not close. And in the meantime I make an Ajax request. And when it's over, only then can I close the 1st alert and view the second.

4) When I click on "OK" on the second alert, the page reloads.

But for the moment I cannot manage well how to display the alerts when I click on OK and Cancel.

I have this code below:

```
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Change to '+planName,
                    text: message,
                    icon: "info",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                    preConfirm: function () {
                        // todo - actually change the plan!
                        $.ajax({
                            url: changeUrl,
                            method: 'POST'
                        }).done(function(){
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Plan changed !',
                                icon: 'success',

                            },function() {
                                location.reload();
                            })
                        });
                    }
                });
```

When I click on CANCEL on the 1st alert, everything is going well.
But if I click OK, then I see the confirmation button go into "loader" but the alert closes directly. Then my Ajax request is made and then displays the second alert.

Could anyone help me please ?

EDIT: current code :

```
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Change to '+planName,
                    text: message,
                    icon: "info",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                    preConfirm: function () {
                        // todo - actually change the plan!
                        return $.ajax({
                            url: changeUrl,
                            method: 'POST'
                        }).done(function(){
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Plan changed !',
                                icon: 'success',

                            },function() {
                                location.reload();
                            })
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Change to '+planName,
  text: message,
  icon: "info",
  showCancelButton: true,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: function () {
    // todo - actually change the plan!
    return $.ajax({
      url: changeUrl,
      method: 'POST'
    }).done(function(){
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Plan changed !',
        icon: 'success',

      },function() {
        location.reload();
      })
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a sandbox with a similar implementation
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-smoke-5gwf0

Comment: Thansk for your  ! It's already better ! When I click OK, the button switches to loading mode and the 1st alert remains while the Ajax request is made. But as soon as the request is finished, the first alert closes but the second does not open.
I tried to follow your directions and get inspired by your code in the sandbox but yet it seems consistent I do not understand. I updated my first post with the current code

Comment: I also tried with your code. In the sandbox, it works, but when I put it in my app 'to test, I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: can you share some link for the same so that I can check it?

Comment: Wow, I think there is a problem ...

https://codepen.io/kiuega/pen/vYEPWwq?editors=1010

Here it works perfectly. And if I test the same code from my app ', it doesn't work.
Except that in my app 'I use webpack-again to load SweetAlert2 globally.

On the other hand, if I insert the CDN of sweetAlert, then it works perfectly for me too. It's weird

Comment: I solved the problem. Amazing ... I deleted the sweetAlert2 package and reinstalled it. And now it works. I don't know why there was a problem before, it's weird

Comment: However the ```location.reload()``` doesn't work in the function() on SweetAlert

Comment: Okay I just added .then(function(){}) instead of ,function() and it works